# Displaying faces in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

Blender is not displaying faces with a dot as usual in *Edit Mode*, *Face Select* mode.

[image]

This is Mavericks OSX, Blender 2.72b

Comment: curious, the only dot I can think of is drawn in wireframe mode.

Comment: Does it show for the default theme?

Comment: Yes, it is showed for the default theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face dots are not displayed if **Textured Solid** is enabled in *3D View >* <kbd>N</kbd>*-panel > Shading*.

Odd theme colors could make it hard to see the face dots, but that's not the reason in your case. Unselected faces use the wire color for both, the edges and the face dot, which is light purple in your screenshot (so clearly distinguishable from the surroundings).

As last resort, [submit a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug) to the tracker.

Comment: That was the reason in my case. OK